# Connecting Spark to Multiple Mongo Collections

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I have the following MongoDB Collections : `employee` and `details`.

Now I have a requirement where I have to get documents from both collections into spark to analyze data.

I tried below code but it seems not working

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DBConnection").setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.app.id","MongoSparkExample")
                .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://localhost/Emp.employee")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g");

SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("Member Log")
                .config(conf).getOrCreate();

SparkConf dailyconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DBConnection").setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.app.id","Mongo Two Example")
                .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://localhost/Emp.details");

SparkSession mongosession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Daily Log")
                .config(dailyconf).getOrCreate();
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems not working" ? A code works or not, there isn't a third option. Please update your question with the relevant part of error that this code is given you if it isn't working. Not all of us knows mongo but many answers can help interpreting the error and thus eventually solving this problem for you.

Comment: Ok so after I formatted your code which is something *you should do*, it seems that you are trying to create 2 spark sessions which will obviously not work and it is also not needed to read 2 collections but I don't know the mongo connector for the syntax. Did you read the documentation ? Can you reference it by editing your question please ? Also can you specify what versions of the frameworks you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by adding below code

```
JavaSparkContext newcontext = new JavaSparkContext(session.sparkContext());
Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
readOverrides.put("collection", "details");
readOverrides.put("readPreference.name", "secondaryPreferred");
ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(newcontext).withOptions(readOverrides);
MongoSpark.load(newcontext,readConfig);
```

Comment: Would you care adding some comment on your code so people understand what you are doing ? Also some doc references if you used them would be valuable

Answer (score 2):

First of all, like eliasah said, you should only create one Spark Session.
Second, take a look at the official [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark) . It provides integration between MongoDB and Apache Spark. It gives you the posibility to load collections in Dataframes.

Please refer to the official documentation:

- [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/)
- [Read from MongoDB (scala)](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/read-from-mongodb/)
- [Read
  from MongoDB (java)](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/java/read-from-mongodb/)

EDIT

The documentation says the following:

> Call loadFromMongoDB() with a ReadConfig object to specify a different MongoDB server address, database and collection.

In your case:

```
sc.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://localhost/Emp.details")))
```

Comment: I see nothing in the official documentation about "using multiple mongo collections". Is it even possible?

Comment: I have edited my answer. This comes from the 'Read from MongoDB (scala)'.

Comment: the scala version of the answerr of MKS

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest Spark SQL features. By passing param as per requirement:

```
sparksession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("TEST")
      .config( "spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongodb://localhost:portNo/dbInputName.CollInputName")
      .config "spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:portNo/dbOutName.CollOutName")
      .getOrCreate()

val readConfigVal = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> uriName,"database" -> dbName, "collection" -> collName, "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred"), Some(ReadConfig(sparksession)))

var mongoLoadedDF = MongoSpark.load(sparksession,readConfig)

println("mongoLoadedDF:"+mongoLoadedDF.show())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write multiple tables using `readOverrides` / `writeOverrides`.

```java
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Mongo connect")
                .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://user:password@ip_addr:27017/database_name.employee")
                .getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

        // Read employee table 1
        JavaMongoRDD<Document> employeeRdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);

        Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // readOverrides.put("database", "database_name");
        readOverrides.put("collection", "details");
        ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(readOverrides);

        // Read another table 2 (details table )
        JavaMongoRDD<Document> detailsRdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc, readConfig);


        System.out.println(employeeRdd.first().toJson());
        System.out.println(detailsRdd.first().toJson());

        jsc.close();
```