# How to import multiple mongo collections into spark Application using Java?

Tags: mongodb, dataset, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Hi I've 2 collections in MongoDB. One contains the actual data and one collection contains model information(meta data).
Now I want to import these two collections into spark application using Java then I'll create two Datasets and I'll do join operation on top of that.

So is it possible to import multiple Mongo collections into Spark using one spark session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting Spark to Multiple Mongo Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061916/connecting-spark-to-multiple-mongo-collections)